# configure domino web server to use internet site document?

Tags: web-server, lotus-notes, ibm-domino

internet site configurations view has -> security options ->

Accept SSL site certificates: default is NO
Accept expired SSL certificates: default is Yes

question: how does this effect server behaviour ?  e.g. if i change the default behaviour ->Accept SSL site certificates to yes  then what effect will it have on server ?

i hope the questions is clear enough, if not please let me know i will rephrase it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a great documentation called the administrator help (in the help directory of your server)... I'd like to say RTFM if it wasn't that impolite...

[here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/super_welcome1_DominoAdmin.html) you can read what these two settings do:

> Accept SSL site certificates
>
> Choose one:
>
> Yes -- To accept the certificate and use SSL , even if the server does not have a certificate in common with the protocol server
>
> No (default) -- To prohibit the acceptance of SSL site certificates for access
>
> Accept expired SSL certificates
>
> Choose one:
>
> Yes -- To allow clients access, even if the client certificate is expired
> No -- To prohibit client access using expired SSL certificates

I don't know, what to describe better than that...

Comment: sound .. i did not know that .. thanks man